# decrese start time of the instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I've setup a batch script that runs on windows machine start up. It's very simple. All it does is to start `apache`, and send a [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) message to my server.

I began to measure that time and noticed that it takes almost 3min for me to get the curl message. That is a very long time. Specially since quick booting time is of critical importance to me.

I am wondering, is there something I can do to decrease the startup time? What configuration should I use to decrease it?

I am already using SSD drive, but would like to know more about if there is a windows operating system and CPU version that lowers the start time the most.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use a script to start apache?

Windows is more than able to start a service on it's own and at a better time than if you wait for the OS to be fully started to launch a script...

You should remove the start of apache from your script and put it in automatic start, then only leave your curl in the script, you may gain some time...

Comment: Thanks for taking your time, I've run tests on a fully OS loaded machines and can confirm that running a service to start apache takes crazy amount of time (10s +), while starting it manually is instant. I am pretty sure it is not the script that is casing issues, because I cannot login to machine as well during that boot time.

Comment: Yes that's because your instance must still be starting, does a windows instance start in less time if you don't have the startup script?

Comment: While still in free trial mode, I would get the curl message in around 2 min. While still bad, it was manageable. Unfortunately google deleted these machines as soon as free trial was over(caused me real headaches), so I do not know if there were any different (cpu wise) from the ones I use now.

Comment: I'll test an report.

Comment: What type of instance are you using? That has a really big impact on startup for windows...

Comment: The time it takes to boot an instance is a little inconsistent. I am now below 2 min even without any script change. Which is...better than 3min, but not exactly in desired range. Omitting apache stratup does not correlate to any noticable time savings. I am using google compute n1-standard-8, CPU Intel Haswell. OS is Windows Server 2016, but there is nothing forcing me to use that WIN OS specifically. I'd love to hear more about what type of instance should I use to speed up boot time.

Comment: Instance type should be big enough to have good startup speed. If you don't need windows specific OS you should take a look at linux based image like Debian, startup speed should be faster than windows.

Comment: Windows in unfortunately mandatory. So basically, there is nothing I can do?

Comment: Not sure I can help more... sorry